# Getting this error on specifically one dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am getting

```
ValueError: `validation_steps=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `validation_steps` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.
```

on specifically one data set (https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/5-celebrity-faces-dataset). I've actually mentioned the validation steps in `.fit_generator( )` and it works fine for all other data sets I'm working on. Is there something wrong with this one?

Here is the snippet of the code which matters (I'm using Keras) :

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

training_data_dir = './train'
validation_data_dir = './validation'
MODEL_FILE='model.h5'

IMAGE_SIZE = 200
IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT = IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
TEST_SIZE = 1
input_shape = (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 3)

training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True)
validation_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_generator = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    training_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="sparse")
validation_generator = validation_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="sparse")

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='nadam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
    training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=len(training_generator.filenames) // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=len(validation_generator.filenames) // BATCH_SIZE, 
    verbose=1)
model.save_weights(MODEL_FILE)
```

Comment: It's easier to debug on Google colab. At least, give us a few lines of stacktrace to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validation_steps=len(validation_generator.filenames) // BATCH_SIZE`  line in `model.fit_generator` method is causing problem. Since, `len(validation_generator.filenames)=25` < `BATCH_SIZE`, which is `32` in above code, therefore `len(validation_generator.filenames) // BATCH_SIZE` comes out to be `0`.

As per the documentation [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), `validation_steps` should typically be equal to the number of samples of your validation dataset divided by the batch size. So, make your `BATCH_SIZE` smaller than or equal to `len(validation_generator.filenames)`.